# Simplified switch library

Tags: javascript

Is there a way ( How ) to implement a library that simplifies the use of switch, I mean instead of it :

```
switch (value) {

    case 0:
    case 1:
        console.log('0 Or 1');
        break;

    case 2:
    case 3:
        console.log('2 Or 3');
        break;

    default:
        console.warn("I don't know");

}
```

We do something like this :

```
switch (value) {

        case 0 || 1: // value === 1 || value === 2 ...
            console.log('0 Or 1');
            break;

        case 2 || 3:
            console.log('2 Or 3');
            break;

        default:
            console.warn("I don't know");

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried? Have you read the [documentation for `switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) (particularly the section entitled ***"Rewriting multiple If statements with Switch"***?

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's horrible code.

Comment: @Bergi The question wasn't about what is/isn't horrible code. The question was if it is possible.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6c8gdh1n/4/

Comment: Yeah, I had read cause Free Code Camp has the reference to this part of doc, I did think in something more direct, anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, you just need to switch `true` instead of value and do the comparison in the `case` expression:

```js
function testSwitch(value) {
  switch (true) {
      case [0,1].includes(value): // value === 1 || value === 2 ...
          console.log('0 Or 1');
          break;

      case [2,3].includes(value):
          console.log('2 Or 3');
          break;

      default:
          console.warn("I don't know");

  }
}

testSwitch(1)
testSwitch(2)
testSwitch(4)
```

Comment: This is hardly a _simplification_ though :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's the truth! :D

Comment: This really should be `if`/`else`

Comment: I do feel this is a little overengineered

Comment: To be clear, I'm not _advocating_ this approach, I'm just answering the question they asked about switch statements handling multiple conditions in one case without using falling through

Answer (score 0):

> Use switch(true) {...}, as follows

```js
var value = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));

switch (true) {

  case value === 0 || value === 1:
    console.log('0 Or 1');
    break;

  case value === 2 || value === 3:
    console.log('2 Or 3');
    break;

  default:
    console.warn("I don't know");

}
```

Comment: This really should be `if`/`else`

Comment: @Bergi I understand that, but I'm not supposed to give my opinion, Stack Overflow is not a place for biased answers.The person asking question wanted to know a way of using switch case, and I answered keeping that in mind.

Comment: @Bergi Why penalize the answer for being correct? The fact that it really should be an `if/else` is off-topic to the question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus If by "penalize" you refer to voting, that's about usefulness not correctness.

Answer (score 0):

You could `switch` on a **pre-processed `value`** though, instead of the original `value` directly.

**Please note:**
Although it feels rather hacky with your example, that **would be the most sensible solution** in most contexts.

```js
function test(value) {
  switch (Math.floor(value / 2)) {
  case 0:
    return ('0 or 1');

  case 1:
    return ('2 or 3');

  default:
    return ("I don't know");
  }
}

[0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(v => {
  console.log(`value: ${v}, result: ${test(v)}`);
});
```

Comment: …and in this context as well!

Comment: This answer is specific to finding `0` or `1` and `2` or `3`, but I suspect the question is more general and asks how to combine possible `case` values into a single `case`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I think this question will mostly pop up when people are searching for a solution to a problem. My solution shows how to actually solve that problem at its root, instead of shoehorning it into a hacky `switch` statement

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus. Rob provides the answer to the question, I provide the answer to the problem (he obviously doesn't advocate the approach featured in his answer). StackOverflow is just better off having both of these answers available!

Comment: @ccjmne: it is indeed more helpful if we can can see the _real_ problem and answer that instead, but what are the chances of being able to deduce the real problem from OP's obviously fake code in this question? For all we know, his actual values are not even integers.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Yes, you're definitely right, his actual values are likely to be much more prone to being pre-processed in a meaningful way!  
Which is my point exactly: In virtually **any** case, this very answer is most definitely the best and probably the **only** solution anybody would reasonably advocate for.